# How to add headers to HttpLink in React Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, token, apollo

I wanted to enter token into my graphql queries. Where I have to put my auth token?

Here is my code in apollo.js:

```
import { withData } from 'next-apollo'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

export const config = {
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/', // Server URL (must be absolute)
    opts: {
      credentials: 'include', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
    }
  })
}

export default withData(config)
```

That's how I make queries:

```
const MYJOBS = gql`
  {
    myJobs {
      role {
        name
      }
      school {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

<Query query={MYJOBS}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, my friend suggested adding `context` to `Query` and it worked!

```
<Query
 query={ME}
 context={{
     headers: {
         authorization: JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}
     }
 }} >
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [apollo-graphql](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html)'s documentation, we can do it this way with setContext - install `apollo-link-context` and do `import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'` at the top of your file:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from whereever it exists - This is your choice.
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/', // Server URL (must be absolute)
    opts: {
      credentials: 'include', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
    }
})
```

And then in your config:

```
export const config = {
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
}
```

This will automatically include the authorization/credentials with every query we make.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new approach using `@apollo/client`:

[Link from official documention](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/basic-http-networking/)